# Lender-of-last-resort institutional setup - are there trade offs?

Tags: macroeconomics, central-banking, financial-stability

In one of his papers, [Minsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyman_Minsky) admonished the fragmented institutional set up that the US market has been using post-depression:

> If the lender-of-Iast-resort function is decentralized so that
> commercial banks and the FDIC do part of the job, then it may be
> necessary for these organizations to act in a way that violates canons
> of good business practice. Commercial banks may be required to acquire
> paper that they really would rather not buy, banks may be required to
> make loans at concessionary terms, and the FDIC may be required to
> choose an expensive, or other than the least costly, way of
> liquidating a failed bank.

For context, by "commercial banks," he seems to be referring to the two-tier structured market of commercial paper: larger institutions have open lines of credit with the Fed while smaller institutions have lines to the large institutions.

But not to get caught up in the technical bits of that part of the passage, I think what we can focus on is his overall analysis. He seems to be arguing that by configuring an institutional setup that spans multiple entities, there would be greater propensity for a type of conflict of interest. Not only are they legally distinct from each other but their commercial interests may be diametrically opposed to towing-the-line of any lender-of-last-resort duty to the broader financial system.

### Question

By taking the more fragmented approach (central bank + deposit insurer + commercial bank) to act as lender-of-last resort, what is the financial system gaining versus a financial system that had a unitary lender-of-last-resort institution? Ideally, I would like to see different countries implementation and/or empirical assessments of such setups to bring any "trade-offs" into real-world context.